# Add a calculated column to pivot table columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to add an extra column that can shows AVG(Marks) foreach row using pivot table if it's possible in sql server.

1-Create Grades Table

```
  CREATE TABLE Grades(
  [Student] VARCHAR(50),
  [Subject] VARCHAR(50),
  [Marks]   INT)
```

2-Inserting some values

```
INSERT INTO Grades VALUES 
('Jacob','Mathematics',100),
('Jacob','Science',95),
('Jacob','Geography',90),
('Amilee','Mathematics',90),
('Amilee','Science',90),
('Amilee','Geography',100)
```

3-Showing results

```
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT[Student],[Subject],[Marks]FROM Grades) StudentResults
  PIVOT (
  MAX([Marks])
  FOR [Subject]
  IN ([Mathematics],[Science],[Geography])) AS PivotTable
```

I need to add column like in this image:

[image]

Comment: Did you tried this approach `Select * , (Mathematics + Science + Geography ) / 3 as 'AVG(Marks)' from
 (SELECT * FROM (SELECT[Student],[Subject],[Marks]FROM Grades) StudentResults
  PIVOT (
  MAX([Marks])
  FOR [Subject]
  IN ([Mathematics],[Science],[Geography])) AS PivotTable ) temp`

Comment: You should be posting an answer, rather than a comment, if you are answering the question, @ahmedabdelqader .

Comment: Assuming any one has all scores, But I don't know how to add this column ?!

Comment: *"I did but doesn't working"* No, you've posted it in a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the window function `avg() over()` in the select which "feeds" your pivot

**Example**

```
 SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT[Student]
             ,[Subject]
             ,[Marks]
             ,[Avg(Marks)] = avg([Marks]) over (partition By [Student])
         FROM Grades) StudentResults
 PIVOT (  MAX([Marks]) FOR [Subject] IN ([Mathematics],[Science],[Geography])) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: @AlecDev Always happy to help.  The window functions can be life savers.  Well worth your time to get comfortable with them.  :)